# Simplifying algebraic fractions.

Tags: fractions

I cannot simplify the following expression. Please need help.

$\large \frac{3}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+3}+\frac{3}{1-x}-\frac{1}{3-x}$

Thanks in advance. Regards !

Comment: How would you simplify $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{11}$?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick like this : $\[\large \frac{5\cdot 7\cdot 11 + 3\cdot 7\cdot 11 + 3\cdot 5\cdot 11 +3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11}\]
$

Comment: Do you see how that relates to your problem?

Comment: Yes I do. But I got this problem after doing factors at college. So I guess you can factorize but I don't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little re-arrangement is needed to make things easier.
$$\frac{3}{x+1} + \frac{3}{1-x} + \frac{1}{x-3} - \frac{1}{x+3}$$
$$3(\frac{1-x+1+x}{1-x^2}) + \frac{x+3-x+3}{x^2-9}$$
$$6(\frac{1}{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2-9})$$
I guess you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: no problem.. :)

Comment: @DavidSebastian: this is the answer that you should leave accepted.  I leave my answer in place as an alternate route to the same conclusion, but this one uses a better path which avoids some of the cancellation confusion that I ran into.

Comment: @abiessu I am new to math.SE and I thought I could accept 2 answers. So I first accepted lsp's one and then yours, which obviously caused lsp's answer to un-accept. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac 3{x+1}-\frac 1{x+3}+\frac 1{x-3}-\frac 3{x-1}$$

$$=\frac {2x+8}{x^2+4x+3}-\frac {2x-8}{x^2-4x+3}$$

$$=\frac {(8-(-8))\cdot 3}{(x^2+3)^2-16x^2}=\frac {48}{x^4-10x^2+9}$$

There's some steps glossed over.